# Add option to show one badge in flair

Tags: feature-request, badges, flair

Badges are a nice way of getting rewarded for reaching certain achievements. Some badges are super easy to earn while others take a lot of patience and effort to get. Similarly people may care more for certain badges and care less for others.

Currently the flair feature shows the total count of bronze, silver and gold badges a user has earned, in bulk, e.g.

[image]

This makes badges get lost in the masses and be just a number.

It would be nice to have a feature that let me choose from my badges the one I care the most about and show that badge in the flair.

It is true the size of the flair is limited so that's why I'd like to suggest two options: make the flair a little taller to make space for the badge OR make the option of displaying the badge mutually exclusive with showings the badges in bulk (gold,silver,bronze), this way the user would have to choose between showing just one badge or showing them all.

Comment: It's fanatic obviously, isn't it? Show the fanatic badge in the flair if someone has it.

Comment: Well, in my case it's the iOS badge. That one makes me proud in a way "student", "commentator", "organizer", "critic", etc, don't

Comment: Unsung Hero. Definitely Unsung Hero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a reasonable request, in per-site flair we do have lots of space though so my mockup:

[image]

Comment: I think it would look better *without* the think border.

Comment: @Dukeling I think we should have *some* border, see my edit.

Comment: What about the same colour / thickness of the outer border (possibly also just square, not rounded)?

Comment: @Dukeling good suggestion, I prefer rounded square though.

Comment: Totally wouldn't work for tags like google-visualization, but otherwise a good idea. I don't even think Strunk & White would fit in that space. Smaller font perhaps? or move the reputation and badges to a single line, with the bottom reserved for the badge?

Comment: @jmac good point! Guess we'll leave that to the graphic designer in charge... :)